# jQuery click and pull down a div (like iOS notification center)

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, resizable, jquery-ui-resizable

I'm aware of the jQuery .toggle() and .slideDown() function but is there a way where the user clicks on an link or item and can pull/slide down the div.

I'm looking to create a similar effect as the iOs notification center where you click on an icon and resize the div to a (defined) height.

Comment: Any particular reason I'm being downvoted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first sentence is confusing. Clicking on a link or item and having the div slide down is basically .slideDown(). If you're just looking to resize a div from a small height to a larger height, try using .animate({height: 200px}, 500) to make the small div grow to 200px over half a second.

Comment: Hi Rich, I'm trying to resize the div but using my mouse. So I click on an icon inside a div and when I move my mouse down the div resizes with the mouse movement down or resizes backup if I move my mouse up. I've found something similar here: http://jsfiddle.net/JXeWA/46/ but it required jquery-ui. I was wondering if it's possible without it.

Comment: OK, yeah, using jquery-ui 'resizable' class is the easiest way to go. Doing it yourself would not be easy at all. Fortunately, it's quite simple to create a custom jquery-ui download that only has the Resizable component.

Comment: A little terminology clarification: When you're holding the left mouse button down and moving the mouse, that's called "dragging." You can also drag a window, which means you're moving the window by dragging on the title bar.

Comment: Thanks! I'll give it a try. English is not my first language so I apologize for the confusion.